# Can I return an Alamo rental car to an Enterprise location?

Tags: usa, car-rentals

I have a car that I rented through Alamo rental but the nearest Alamo location is over an hour from me, not to mention traffic.

Can I return the Alamo car to the Enterprise (a parent company of Alamo) location 30 minutes or less from me.

I am located in Newark, Texas.

Comment: Call your rental company, only the will be able to tell.

Comment: I'm not sure why you expect to be able to return to a different rental company...

Comment: Enterprize is the father company of Alamo. I was just trying to return the car at a closer location.

Comment: @choster they are all the same company according to https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enterprise_Holdings

Comment: Why the downvotes? It's a realistic question, and based on Martin's link, might be true even, but even if it was ridiculous it's clearly an honest travel question, from a new user.

Comment: While Enterprise, Alamo and National are all owned by the same parent company, they are three independent companies with their own fleets.  So your reservation and bill are on the Alamo system, not the Enterprise system.  It never hurts to ask, but don't get your hopes up.

Comment: I seem to recall having successfully done this once.  I needed to drop off a car after the Enterprise office was closed, and I think I was told to take it to the Alamo location at the same airport.  As I recall, it took the staff a little longer to figure out how to process the return paperwork, but it was sorted out in the end.  But I agree you shouldn't just assume it will work; call and ask.

Comment: In my personal experience, they don't care much over mixing vehicles if it is at the same location; but that might be different for a one-only location. For sure, it will be a one-way rental, whihc probably would cost you for the miles. Significantly.

Comment: I was able to return the car to a local enterprize so just know it can be done. Thank you all for the helpful information.

Comment: @DarlaBethany - you could write that into an answer (perhaps including anything special you had to do to make it happen). It's perfectly ok to answer your own question, and it'll help the next person who has the same question.

Answer (score 2):

In Malaga airport, in Spain, at peak times the various car rental companies (Avis, Enterprise, EuropCar and other local ones) seem to have a share deal where they all interchange cars as needed (probably cross-charging) in order to cope with times of high demand. And they aren't even part of the same group!

So it is absolutely possible that you could do this - but you'd need to check first, otherwise they'll be very confused...